# Django-rest cross origin request fails

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I have installed `django-cors-headers` and my seetings.py has following:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework_docs',
    'tasks'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

However, I still get  `Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response` error when I hit the url from my Angular frontend.

Am I missing any configuration?

Comment: Have you ran `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Comment: Yes, there were no new migrations to apply

Comment: Also, put `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` in your settings.py.

Comment: It did not help either :(

Comment: Could you show your post request data or some code of your request?

Comment: Hey I figured it out, see my answer. Thanks a lot anyway..

Answer (score 1):

You need to add:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False
```

To your settings.py too and it will work ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't on backend side, I had a function in my angular service as following:

```
  getTasks(): Observable<Task[]> {

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get(this.taskUrl, options)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Which had to be:

```
  getTasks(): Observable<Task[]> {

    return this.http.get(this.taskUrl)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked when backend(django) and frontend(angular) worked on the same hosts. Like django server on localhost:8000 and angular server on localhost:4200.